# Forming training set for Multinomial Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes, train

Is it true that Multinomial Naive Bayes requires equally by count training data for each class to get best performance?

For example, we forming classifier for three classes - Japan, China, Korea.

For Japan available 500 training data, China - 300, Korea - 100.

So to train Multinomial Naive Bayes we need to get only 100 data for each class inspite of we have 500 for Japan, 300 for China.

I know that we can train Naive Bayes with all available data, but in this case we got worse performance, is it true?

Comment: I found answer here http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICML/2003/ICML03-081.pdf !

Comment: But I get another question: Is it the same for the classifiers like SVM?